# Magento2 - How to stop redirecting to Shopping cart on canceling Paypal payment?

Tags: magento2, paypal

In default Magento2, on canceling paypal express checkout (closing the paypal popup), redirects to the Shopping Cart. Is there an easy way to stop redirecting to shopping cart and display the success/error messages on checkout page itself?
Any help/suggestion is appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In case, of PayPal express checkout, the redirect can be changed in below file

vendor/magento/module-paypal/Controller/Express/AbstractExpress/Cancel.php

Change the line

```
return $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
```

to

```
return $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout');
```

Obviously, please don't modify the file directly and instead rewrite it using Magento 2's preferences :)

For other PayPal methods, it can be found under related controller file under the directory

vendor/magento/module-paypal/Controller

Comment: But this is not helping me to resolve my problem. The problem is, in case of guest customer if the checkout page is refreshed then the previously entered shipping address will not be fetched by Magento and guest has to re-enter shipping address.  Here 2 approaches I can think of 1) On PayPal cancel, do not refresh page and show message on checkout itself. 2) Save shipping address details for guest checkout and fetch it on refresh of checkout page.